# Why does not wotk routeProvider in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I use routeProvider in Angular JS:

```
.when('/chat/dialog/:id', {
     controller: 'ChatController'
});
```

In controller I have:

```
if($routeParams.id) {
   alert('ok');
}
```

And my **URL** looks like as:

```
http://site-dev.com/chat/dialog/1
```

**Link** is: `<a href="/chat/dialog/1"></a>`

Why does not work routing in Angular JS?

**Controller:**

```
.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', '$sce', '$http', '$location', '$anchorScroll', '$timeout', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $sce, $http, $location, $anchorScroll, $timeout, $routeParams, ) {

    if($routeParams.id) {
       alert('ok');
   }
}])
```

**Routing:**

```
.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            .when('/profile/personal/:type', {
                templateUrl: '/public/html/personal.html',
                controller: 'EditProfileController'
            })

            /* Chat */
            .when('/chat/dialog/:id', {
                controller: 'ChatController'
            });
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more detailed code? Your full route configuration, your controller code. Also, what doesn't work? the routing? or the alert? or something else? if it's the alert in the conditional, one guess would be that you are not injecting $routeParams into the controller

Comment: Does not work `alert()`, I updated question added more details

Comment: Looks like you have an extra comma in the function definition - function ($scope, $sce, $http, $location, $anchorScroll, $timeout, $routeParams, ) <-- here

Comment: No, sorry, in code there is not comma

Answer (score -1):

Try to add into `head` tag `<base href="/">`, like this:

```
<head>
   <base href="/">
</head>
```

Comment: Did you injected ngRoute into your app?

Comment: First try to check if you can acess id in url with one level : '/chat/:id'

Comment: Can explain more about it please